# Add row and write ticketId automatically in Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, controller, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I want to insert the ticketId to insert the data in the table that I created with add row. Now I can get the user_id to be written, but I have not yet written `ticketId`. The table is the same, and I have the `ticketId` field. How can I recall the `ticketId`?. I also need to write the `ticketId`. How can I add it?

**Controller**

```
public function addMorePost(Request $request, $ticketId)
{
    $request->validate([
        'addmore.*.desc_art' => 'required',
        'addmore.*.marca' => 'required',
        'addmore.*.modello' => 'required',
        'addmore.*.unita' => 'required',
        'addmore.*.quantita' => 'required',
    ]);

    foreach ($request->addmore as $key => $value) {
        TicketReply::create(array_merge($value, 
            ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]));
    }

    return back()->with('eseguito', 'Materiale Caricato.');
}
```

```js
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var i = 0;

            $("#add").click(function(){

                ++i;

                $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][desc_art]" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][marca]" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][modello]" class="form-control" /></td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][unita]" class="form-control" /<td><td><input type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][quantita]" class="form-control" /></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Rimuovi</button></td></tr>');
            });

            $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            });
        </script>
```

```html
 <table class="table-responsive" id="dynamicTable">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Descrizione</th>
                        <th>Marca</th>
                        <th>Modello</th>
                        <th>Unità</th>
                        <th>Quantità</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][desc_art]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][marca]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][modello]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="addmore[0][unita]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="addmore[0][quantita]" class="form-control" /></td>
                        <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Aggiungi</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button type="submit" id="dynamicTable" class="btn btn-primary ">Salva</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: where is the `post_id` field in your code?

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong, it's ticketid

Comment: did you try to add it in the same array with user_id :`array_merge($value,['user_id' => Auth::user()->id,'ticketId'=>$ticketId])`

Comment: I tried like this, but it no longer writes me anything in the database, I did this test without success in the model is fillable

Comment: can you share more code from your `TicketReply` Model and the `ticket_replies` table structure ?. because what is obvious until now is what @rafahmnjd // did you did `ticketId` ?

Comment: class TicketReply extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [

        'desc_art', 'marca', 'modello', 'unita', 'quantita', 'user_id', 'ticket_id'

    ];

Comment: I added table and script in the post, in the comment it is too long and does not allow me

Comment: solved i found the problem, thanks i had to write the code and now it works, thanks for the support ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'ticket_id' =>$ticketid]));